# Which statistical test should i use? [I have conducted an experiment with two conditions (happy and sad)]

Tags: spss, hypothesis-testing

I have conducted an experiment with two conditions (happy and sad) i wanted to see the effects of these conditions on words chosen from three different categories (positive, negative and neutral words)

- in both conditions I have data on the three different word categories
- its a between subjects design - their were different participants in each condition

The IV is the mood condition either happy or sad.

The DV is relative frequency of words in pos, neg and neutral categories

I want to find a statistical test which will show me if there is a difference between the relative frequencies in each word category in the two different conditions

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression.

Comment: Is there any meaningful difference in the overall length of text either subject produces? I might imagine that these mood conditions affect the overall willingness to share anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by ignoring the neutrals to make the DV 1-dimensional: You would test the ratio between just positive and negative words. In dimension 1, there's easy non-parametric tests (e.g. permutation test for difference in mean https://thomasleeper.com/Rcourse/Tutorials/permutationtests.html).

If such a test fails, then the pos/neg ratio is not the same, and thus the relative frequencies are not the same.